# How to hide columns with no data in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Need to find a way to hide columns that contain null as the data point in Highcharts.

Example:
I have data that is distributed over values of X, Y, and Z.
The categories are A B C, each potentially with values for X,Y,Z.
For columns where either X, Y, or Z are null, I'd like to hide the bar (i.e. collapse the bar so that it doesn't take up space)

Requested Behavior:

> .    Xa Za Xb Xc Yc Zc
>   5     I
>   4     I    I
>   3     I    I    I    I
>   2     I    I    I    I    I
>   1     I    I    I    I    I    I
>   0 ---A--- -B- -----C------

Basically, when B (in the case above) has null for Y and Z I want those columns to collapse but be visible when C has data for A, B, and C.

Let me know if this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: the only solution that come to my mind is generating the categories array according to the data and removing the null values from the series.data

Answer (score 0):

Use [chart.events.load](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) to detect null values and the use [chart-update](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/chart-update) method to update it

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var chart = this;
    var data = chart.series[0].processedYData;
    var categories = chart.series[0].xAxis.categories;

    var filteredData, filterdCategories;
    chart.series[0].processedYData.forEach(function(value, key) {
      if (value == null) {
        filteredData = data.filter((v, i) => i !== key)
        filterdCategories = categories.filter((v, i) => i !== key)
        chart.update({
          xAxis: {
            categories: filterdCategories
          },
          series: {
            data: filteredData
          }
        })
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this;
        var data = chart.series[0].processedYData;
        var categories = chart.series[0].xAxis.categories;
        
        var filteredData, filterdCategories;
        chart.series[0].processedYData.forEach(function(value, key) {
          if (value == null) {
            filteredData = data.filter((v, i) => i !== key)
            filterdCategories = categories.filter((v, i) => i !== key)
            chart.update({
              xAxis: {
                categories: filterdCategories
              },
              series: {
                data: filteredData
              }
            })
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      'Jan',
      'Feb',
      'Mar',
      'Apr',
      'May',
      'Jun',
      'Jul',
      'Aug',
      'Sep',
      'Oct',
      'Nov',
      'Dec'
    ],
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, null, 129.2, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, null, 54.4]

  }]

})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Problem is I always want the categories to stay. I want to get rid of columns per category when they contain null values. In the example you're removing categories, not collapsing columns. (Sorry that I wasn't clear). Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: You’re welcome. I am waiting for you answer post. I want to know what you actually want.

Comment: Refer to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/4j7L3rdg/ So the problem here is that the blue column on  the `B` category should be centered (black series shouldn't take any space if it has `null` value in this category)?